# How to change a Variable on an Instance of a Player with Network Manager?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unet

So I am trying to change a variable on a player object by clicking a button using Unet. However, I am having trouble getting the instance of the player object. Is there a way to get the instance of a player from the Network Manager component? I can change the variable before the player connects but once they are connected I can no longer modify it.

Is there a way to do this?

I have a PlayerController script and all I basically want to do is change an integer on my player object based on a button press. I have tried referencing the gameObject attached to the script with `gameObject` and `this`. That doesn't seem to work and I have also tried `player.GetComponent<PlayerController>().myInt` and that doesn't seem to change it either.

All of these methods work until I connect as a Host or client and then it just doesn't do anything once I am connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured this out in the very depths of the terrible documentation that I could find.

`GameObject player = FindObjectOfType<NetworkManager>().client.connection.playerControllers[0].gameObject;`